# Typescript conditionally make certain properties optional

Tags: typescript

I'm currently trying to make a utility type to unwrap sniptt monads Options. Here's my code so far:

```js
export interface Option<T> {
  type: symbol;
  isSome(): boolean;
  isNone(): boolean;
  match<U>(fn: Match<T, U>): U;
  map<U>(fn: (val: T) => U): Option<U>;
  andThen<U>(fn: (val: T) => Option<U>): Option<U>;
  or<U>(optb: Option<U>): Option<T | U>;
  and<U>(optb: Option<U>): Option<U>;
  unwrapOr(def: T): T;
  unwrap(): T | never;
}

export type UnwrappedOptionsType<T> = T extends (infer U)[]
  ? UnwrappedOptionsType<U>[]
  : T extends object
  ? {
      [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends Option<infer R>
        ? UnwrappedOptionsType<R> | undefined
        : UnwrappedOptionsType<T[P]>;
    }
  : T;
```

What I expect to happen is that types get inferred and properties that are Options are optional. Suppose I have the following type:

```js
type SignUpRequest = {
    username: string;
    password: string;
    email: Option<string>;
}
```

When I use `UnwrappedOptionsType<SignUpRequest>`, I expect to get the following type:

```js
{
    username: string;
    password: string;
    email?: string | undefined;
}
```

What I get instead:

```js
{
    username: string;
    password: string;
    email: string;
}
```

It's able to successfully infer the type of the option, but it never makes it so that it also accepts `undefined`. How do I make the options optional?

**Edit**: Changed code to make example reproducible. Also, I specifically want the properties to be optional, not just possibly undefined.

Comment: What is "sniptt monads Options"?  Could you [edit] the code to make it a self-contained [mre] that doesn't depend on any third-party code?  That way we can just paste it into a standalone IDE, see the issue, and hopefully fix it.  Also note that in `{x: string | undefined}`, `x` is not optional, it is required but allowed to be `undefined`. Do you care about optional (like `{x?: string}`)?  Or is required-but-could-be-`undefined` good enough for you?

Comment: Presumably you care about nested properties; could you update your example to show what you want to happen there?  Also, what about unions?  Should `{x: string | Option<number>}` become `{x: string | number | undefined}` or `{x?: string | number}` or `{x: string} | {x?: number}` or something else?

Comment: I mean, [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/Na440w) would be my inclination here, but I don't know if it behaves as you desire with edge cases.  How should we proceed?

Comment: @jcalz That works perfectly for me. I'll accept it as an answer if you post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one possible approach:

```
type UnwrapOptions<T> =
    T extends Option<infer U> ? UnwrapOptions<U> | undefined :
    T extends readonly any[] ? {[I in keyof T]: UnwrapOptions<T[I]>} :
    T extends object ? (
        { [K in keyof T as Option<any> extends T[K] ? never : K]: UnwrapOptions<T[K]> } &
        { [K in keyof T as Option<any> extends T[K] ? K : never]?: UnwrapOptions<T[K]> }
    ) extends infer U ? { [K in keyof U]: U[K] } : never :
    T;
```

This is a [recursive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#recursive-conditional-types), and as such, there are bound to be lots of edge cases where it behaves in a surprising or undesirable way.  So before you use this, or something else, you should make sure to do lots of testing.

Okay, let's examine it. If you evaluate `UnwrapOptions<T>` where `T` is...

- ...`Option<U>` for some type `U`, then we recursively evaluate `UnwrapOptions<U>` (if you might be nesting `Option`s), and return it in a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) with `undefined`.  This `undefined` is probably only needed if the `Option` is top-level.  That is, `UnwrapOptions<Option<A>>` should be `UnwrapOptions<A> | undefined`;
- ...an array or [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types), then we do a simple [mapped array/tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) where `UnwrapOptions` is applied to each numeric element.  That is, `UnwrapOptions<[A, B]>` should be `[UnwrapOptions<A>, UnwrapOptions<B>]`;
- ...a primitive type, then we return that primitive type.  That is, `UnwrapOptions<string>` should be `string`, etc;
- ...a non-array object type, then we need to split the object into its `Option`-assignable properties and its non-`Option`-assignable properties.  For those which are *not* `Option` assignable, we just do a straight [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) where `UnwrapOptions` is applied to each property.  For those which *are* `Option` assignable, we do the same thing, but use the `?` [mapping modifier](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#mapping-modifiers) to make all the properties [optional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties).  We then have to join these two halves back together with an [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types).  That's enough to give the types you want, but intersections can be ugly; since an intersection of object types like `{a: 0} & {b: 1}` is equivalent to a single object type like `{a: 0; b: 1}`, I use [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) to copy the intersection into a new type argument `U`, and then do a no-op mapped type to join the intersection into one type.

---

Okay, let's test it.

```
type SignUpRequest = {
    username: string;
    password: string;
    email: Option<string>;
}

type UnwrappedSignupRequest = UnwrapOptions<SignUpRequest>;
/* type UnwrappedSignupRequest = {
    username: string;
    password: string;
    email?: string | undefined;
} */
```

That's what you wanted.  What if we take a more complicated type?

```
interface Foo {
    a: string;
    b?: number;
    c: string[];
    d: { z?: string };
    e: Option<number>;
    f: Option<string>[];
    g: Option<string> | number;
    h: [1, Option<2>, 3];
    i: { y: Option<string> };
    j: Option<{ x: Option<{ w: string }> }>;
    k: Foo;
}
```

That becomes

```
type UnwrappedFoo = UnwrapOptions<Foo>;
/* type UnwrappedFoo = {
    a: string;
    b?: number | undefined;
    c: string[];
    d: {
        z?: string | undefined;
    };
    f: (string | undefined)[];
    h: [1, 2 | undefined, 3];
    i: {
        y?: string | undefined;
    };
    k: any; // <-- this displays as any but it is not
    e?: number | undefined;
    g?: string | number | undefined;
    j?: {
        x?: {
            w: string;
        } | undefined;
    } | undefined;
} */
```

which is reasonable, I think.  The only confusing bit is that IntelliSense displays the recursive part (the `k` property) as `any`.  But it actually does keep track of that type, which you can see if you inspect a property:

```
declare const uFoo: UnwrappedFoo;
uFoo.k;
/* (property) k: {
    a: string;
    b?: number | undefined;
    c: string[];
    d: {
        z?: string | undefined;
    };
    f: (string | undefined)[];
    h: [1, 2 | undefined, 3];
    i: {
        y?: string | undefined;
    };
    k: any;
    e?: number | undefined;
    g?: string | number | undefined;
    j?: {
        x?: {
            w: string;
        } | undefined;
    } | undefined;
} */
```

So there you go, looks good to me, I think.  But you should test it and update accordingly.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgeTBgQiQB4AVAPjgG8AoOJuGATzGAC44BnVgWwBGEADYBuRswQ8AyhH7AAFAEpuw0cExIJzRDwBypJarjqRm7ZKYB6a3H6YY2ABZkAqlUXok3ALKOXSgAaOA8TNzE4MgBaaJZnaTgAEwhgHiQAcnhQaRgre0wwd09vbkUAN0wRbgplOABeGjcTQmJSYp1mLSSKZ2ByDy8fOAqqmrrGgiISAaoW6faPTqZoYsUIIkFuVpni+bbyCjgAH1CqZbhutY2YLamDve2F2YuAVyQAdyhC-ChFJOA6HGNTen2+YBUNROcCQwHKaAkAF96PQ2BxQmCfs8eJQaPV8kdQKgkEkePddsh0GgznAAPwYr5Yg44jzQ94A9DIYBJOCcAlwIn9UlwKCaFJIESsS5IVgAbQAunS6HBZQBJRBIOAAa2ArAg6DgFHl3DcmLAO1IOIoavlNERvP5gpJZIgggAVsBsPB6Yp8rpaCqANIa7W6-WGy5ki3kLSsGhO4XWwOK+mw+FQXlwZMms3Rq2y5N2uAAMj9zADBZDOr1BqOmCjzzIsfjIGJiYLKazmbTaHltJzjPN2MoHbt+TqCbJlOpbiVFeDyFDNdCxtCHbg9u4PYzfN0FAkKLReBkCAA5kg3GAAErAACOrzS8HqdHyrx4aCQmAU3B4MCgyFPC4wHrHgPmgJIfz-ACLmABwEGqcl2l-f8kFPc56GRVF2DwU1Bw4JIT3PV5rzvB9fwaBlwTzMhCIvEj70fdDrAAKhYbDKMKfDaOIm8GPI58GF0N8Py-LheCg1CgJAsCoAg8SUMA-JYMweD+3kgC2RJQEuSSJE4GY6wUWQVAMBwPAADEIAgF9dEwSCFIuQQ1KQV4hARfJsHsgCFQuOSAwALzU5CNMRGCngeFy3KgdDdCBRDyGC1CqB8-JT3C3ZErQ6FIsEdzdGcbhZQARhCaMyAAJioEIAGZ5QuBBuADVh0qQiSstC-I3Ra8gAxAbqyADD4vNQjc7Ri5gtW4SyICRQ92Nw8F8OmiiFqZGYcWmpjWKPDiwCWqyKMErphsU3QnK3VzcozU52W02FdI8k6Ut0PyyyYQKTs0jkdIuDrYrKTKvru7llGe5gCpVEq4HKoHOXumq6vyBqbN0ZhWCCtrYZ+-I-om7hY0iWwolieJEiSaQwBETBWDJetpSlQRXngBBmbJJAIDyXRgGcy7qRurS4e5C5TwxhTst5664FuwWHt0N01KO1G4BABW3tRob1MktX7X5777t+rH9Yw-TDPoAFsCp0U4GwS14FeaaB0W7lpoke2rIAOi1CQWJGMAoA2NA2DqSaUaYOzNdO5hzphCXDaFx6I7BphXqV97RY03Xgdl5hcaYOLFEBzOZdBxH8sKqGYaLnSEfqxq1fRz6q6N3Rc+1fGZRgnmorj7OmBFxuY+7pv47l1XU+Vsfx+YDXMouFue4N4eHvtAygA)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add an additional type guard to your UnwrappedOptionsType type to make the option optional:

```
type UnwrappedOptionsType<T> = T extends (infer U)[]
  ? UnwrappedOptionsType<U>[]
  : T extends object
  ? {
      [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends Option<infer R>
        ? (UnwrappedOptionsType<R> | undefined) | undefined
        : UnwrappedOptionsType<T[P]>;
    }
  : T;
```

With the addition of the type guard, the UnwrappedOptionsType for the SignUpRequest type will be:

```
type UnwrappedOptionsType<SignUpRequest> = {
    username: string;
    password: string;
    email?: (string | undefined) | undefined;
}
```

The output will look like this:

```
{
    username: string;
    password: string;
    email?: string | undefined;
}
```

Is that what you're going after?